# Python Generated MySQL Insert Statement converting to handle 'on duplicate'

Tags: python, mysql

I have the python code below that generically inserts values in to a mysql db.  It checks the length of my list `field_split` and builds a variable string `var_string`.   Where I am stuck is that I want to modify this to support `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE user=user_id_var`.   If I was building a long string I would know how to do this but couldn't figure out a way to do it by passing two values to `cursor.execute`.

```
var_string = ', '.join(['%s'] * len(field_split))
query_string = 'INSERT into ' + table_name 
query_string = query_string + ' VALUES (%s);' % var_string  #query_string = 'INSERT INTO tbl_rtp_GET_FBA_ESTIMATED_FBA_FEES_TXT_DATA VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s);'
cursor.execute(query_string, field_split)
db.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just construct the query and pass all the parameters as a single sequence to `cursor.execute()`. You can also use `str.format()` to avoid multiple string concatenations, which can be slow:

```
var_string = ', '.join(['%s'] * len(field_split))
query_string = 'INSERT into {} VALUES ({}) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE user=%s'.format(
    table_name, var_string)
cursor.execute(query_string, field_split + [user_id_var])
db.commit()
```